# Extract data from a form to login in an android app

Tags: android, forms, kotlin, web, networking

I'm developing an app for Android with Android Studio/Kotlin, this is my very first project.

I would like to login to my HP Instant Ink in my app https://instantink.hpconnected.com/fr/fr/l/ but I don't know how to extract the form datas (URL, parameters). I've tried with the Chrome console but I was not successful.

Would anyone be kind enough to help me ? Please tell me how you did, this is important for me to understand.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is login from?